# How to install asteriskwin32 using cygwin?

Tags: asterisk, sip-server

I have errors when trying to install asteriskwin32 on Windows Server 2008. Can anyone tell me how to install asterisk on the WS operating system with cgywin?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend a new approach, outlined over at Nerd Vittles:

http://nerdvittles.com/index.php?p=194